# How do you pass SOME_LIB="-lmylib -lmylib2" in a BUILD_COMMAND for ExternalProject_Add()?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to pass a quoted string through BUILD_COMMAND in ExternalProject_Add() and every way I try it's getting mangled.  The code is this:

```
set (mylibs "-lmylib -lmylib2")
ExternalProject_Add(Foo
    URL             http://foo
    BUILD_COMMAND   make SOME_LIB=${mylibs}
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    ...)
```

I've tried using backslash quotes, double quotes, inlining the whole thing, but every time, either the whole SOME_LIB=... part gets quoted or my injected quotes get escaped.  Is it not possible to get quotes through to the command line so they just cover the parameters?

Even though I'm unable to get the resulting make call to look like `make SOMELIB="-lmylib -lmylib2"`, you can make it call `make "SOMELIB=-lmylib -lmylib2"` which seems to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried quoting like this?

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  ...
  BUILD_COMMAND make "SOME_LIB=\"${mylibs}\""
  ...
)
```

The outer pair of double quotes says "this is all one argument here", and the inner pair of escaped double quotes says "these are embedded IN the argument".

It may need extra escaping, though. I haven't tried this and I'm not certain it will work. But there should be a way to add escape characters until it does work... Or, worst case, you could write out a script file (bash .sh or batch .bat) that has proper shell syntax for calling make like you want it and then invoke executing the script file as the BUILD_COMMAND.